# how to get a dynamic array using struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

In the code below I have my cars array set to max length of `10000`, but what should I do if I want to set the array size to a number that the user will input?

```
#define MAX 10000

typedef struct Car{
    char model[20];
    char numberCode[20];
    float weight, height, width, length;
}cars[MAX];
```

Comment: Do you know how to use [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) for the primitive types like `int`? Then you know how to dynamically allocate memory for a structure as well.

Comment: I'm currently studying how to use them. But they seem complicated to me.

Comment: Also the typedef keyword is used, so cars is not an object.

Comment: This will probably make a type definition of an array instead of creating an array of objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h> /*Header for using malloc and free*/

typedef struct Car{
    char model[20];
    char numberCode[20];
    float weight, height, width, lenght;
} Car_t;
/*^^^^^^ <-- Type name */

Car_t *pCars = malloc(numOfCars * sizeof(Car_t));
/*                       ^            ^         */
/*                      count     size of object*/
if(pCars) {
  /* Use pCars[0], pCars[1] ... pCars[numOfCars - 1] */
  ...
} else {
  /* Memory allocation failed. */
}
...
free(pCars); /* Dont forget to free at last to avoid memory leaks */
```

When you write:

```
typedef struct Car{
  ...
}cars[MAX];
```

cars is a type which is a composite type containing `MAX` cars and possibly this is not something you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all use typedef like this

```
typedef struct Car
{
   char model[20];
   char numberCode[20];
   float weight, height, width, lenght;
}car_type;
```

Then in main() you go like this:

```
 main()
 {
    ...
   int n;
   scanf("%d",&n);
   car_type *cars =(car_type *) malloc(n*sizeof(car_type));
    ...  
 }
```